# unable to change MySQL column to have the NOT NULL constraint

Tags: mysql, syntax, alter

I'm trying to change a bunch of columns in my MySQL database to have the NOT NULL constraint using the following:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Jobs CHANGE Date_to_Run Date_to_Run NOT NULL;
```

I thought that that was how you made such a change but it's giving me a syntax error.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the error

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: can you post the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what's wrong:

```
ALTER TABLE Jobs CHANGE Date_to_Run Date_to_Run NOT NULL;
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ need to specify the data type
                 ^^^^^ it's MODIFY, not CHANGE
```

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Jobs MODIFY Date_to_Run DATE NOT NULL;
```

I'm assuming it's type `DATE` - if not just put in the actual type instead of `DATE`, then follow it by `NOT NULL`.

The `ALTER TABLE` docs are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: btw, is there a command to in MySQL to make every column in a table have the NOT NULL constraint?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'm 99% sure you have to modify them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is this:
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype not null

you can see it on this site:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp